# Detect and qualify flash memory (sd card) wear

Tags: usb-flash-drive, sd-card, benchmarking, memory-card, compact-flash

What is the best way to detect and evaluate/qualify flash memory wear that usually occurs after a lot of data has been written the flash? I mean especially a wear caused by continuous writes by dash cams which record video in a loop to a micro-sd cards.

Any open-source (Linux based) tools available for this? Or is it enough to simply test writes? If so, which utility is best for it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any method of extracting wear information from the card, given that it doesn't support SMART (which would do the job fine). You may find that the manufacturer can supply a utility that does something special to check the card but this is not likely.

I suggest you try:  f3write, and f3read. f3write fills a file system up with 1GB files named NNNN.fff, where N is a number. Whereas, f3read validates those files. from the site: https://fixfakeflash.wordpress.com/

While the intent of those programs is to check for fake flash chips, I would expect it to work just as well for checking how much of the card is still usable.